# Как перевести строки из list в int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытался `fov = int(fov)` но выдаёт `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"'`

```
import configparser as cfg
config = cfg.ConfigParser()
config.read("settings.ini")

fov = config["NAIM"]["fov"]
print(fov + 1)
```

Вывод: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

```
print(fov)
```

Вывод: `"100"`

Comment: Как выглядит fov (через print) ?

Comment: @MBo Вывод: "100"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"'` говорит о том, что ваше число в строке вместе с кавычками. То есть что то вроде этого: `fov='"100"'`. Можно попробовать что то наворотить, но не думаю, что вашей задачи не подойдет простое решение в виде fov[1 : (-1)]. По факту еденичным отступом от левого и правого края строки можно убрать кавычки. Последующих ошибок при конвертировании в целочисленное не должно возникнуть.

`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`. Итератор не может понять, что именно вы от него хотите. Или конвертируйте еденицу справа в строку и склеивайте строки, или конвертируйте строку слева в число, и складывайте числа. Как я понял, вам нужно последнее. Что-ж. Уже решено выше.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё получилось!

Comment: @usepy, если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его галочкой, так другие пользователю будут знать что решение найдено

Answer (score 1):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"'
```

Свидетельствует о том, что вместо «100» парсер конфига отдаёт «"100"» (что и видно на принте).

Решить это можно написав:

```
fov = config["NAIM"]["fov"]
fov = fov.strip('"') # <=== // Убирает в начале и конце «"»
fov = int(fov)
```